# How to make Jenkins send email if build is broken for a long time

Tags: jenkins

I need to make Jenkins send an email if a build is broken and unclaimed after, say, two hours. Is there a setting/plugin available that will do this?

Comment: You can also consider using one of the [monitoring tools](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+Jenkins) that will sit in tray and show a red light until the build is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the built-in e-mail system is not capable of handling your specific request.

For reference : from the home page, follow "Manage Jenkins", then go to the "Configure System" page and look for the "Email notification" section near the bottom (sorry for possible wording discrepancies, this is translated from my French Jenkins).

I haven't used it but the "Extensible E-mail" plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) offers much more configurability, including what triggers the sending of a notification e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

The **[email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)** (Editable Email Notification) allows a ton of customization, including triggering email based on script logic (which you can write yourself)